# Package 3 chars of Array into an integer C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char, integer

So, i have this array which contains a bunch of numbers. I want to always take 3 of those chars and make one integer out of them. I haven't found anything on this yet.
here is an example:

```
string number = "123456xyz";
```

The string is what I have, these integers are what I want

```
int goal1 = 123;
int goal2 = 456;
int goaln = xyz;
```

It should go through all the chars and always split them into groups of three. I think foreach() is going to help me, but im not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: `char` is efficiently `Int16` that's why `3 char` should be `Int48` (.Net doesn't have such type); so in general case you can't pack 3 `char`s into single `int` (which is `Int32`) but can into `long` (`Int64`)

Comment: you can use a for loop to iterate through the strings chars and do a modulus on the current index to find out if you have 3 yet

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var goals = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i + 2 < number.Length; i += 3)
{
  goals.Add(int.Parse(number.Substring(i,3)));
}
```

This has no error checking but it shows the general outline.  Foreach isn't a great option because it would go through the characters one at a time when you want to look at them three at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(number, @"\d{3}")
    select m.Value).ToList();

var goal1 = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[0]);
var goal2 = Convert.ToInt32(numbers[1]);
...
```